# Open image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery filetree to browse files on server. I have set up that if any other file except jpg,png or gif is clicked file downloads. Problem is I cannot figure out how to open images in my browser. My code below:

```
function openFile(file) {
var extension = file.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
    switch(extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'png':
        case 'gif':
            //some great solution needed here
        break;                         
        default:
            window.location.href= 'download.php?file='+file;;
    }


}
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that. Just `window.location.href = 'path/to/image/file'`

Comment: using window.location.href does not work. Link looks good but not found comes up

Comment: the problem might be that my site is located at home/ersda/rnis but the file im looking for is below my root folder at : home/ersda/share/files/0AS0450/Sources/Koala.jpg